# Overlay SVG on top of tbody of table

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is it possible to overlay an SVG canvas on top of a scrollable tbody? I need to draw lines between div in my trs. If it is possible to overlay an SVG canvas on a scrollable tbody any examples are much appreciated.

Following is example of the table I am working with, table overflow is auto. In this example I am trying to draw a line between "Connection 1" and "Connection 2" and I am looking to make the line remain connected to those two components when I scroll the table left/right or up/down.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1 </th>


      <th>2 </th>

      <th>3 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <svg style="
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
</svg>
    <tr style="height: 30px;">
      <td style="position: absolute; left: 100px;">
        <div>Connection 1 </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px;">
      <td>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 200px;">Connection 2 </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px;">
      <td>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 400px;">Connection 3 </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Why not just post the code you have and we'll explain where you're going wrong.

Comment: SVG elements in canvas elements are 2 different things..

Comment: @RobertLongson I've added the example of the table I am working with if you can add any insights that would be very helpful.

Comment: There's no <svg> tags in there.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've added the SVG tag that I'm working with. SVG canvas goes over the whole page, rather only being on the tbody content.

Comment: This is not a valid HTML. First of all you have an svg element inside the table but outside any cell. Then you have a row with 3 th but next the other rows have only one td each

Comment: I was able to get it to work, I had to go table and tbody  position relative and SVG in the tbody with position absolute, width 100% and height 100%

Comment: This is a sound approach. You should add that as your answer below and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, I had to go `position: relative;` for `<table>` and `<tbody>` and `<svg>` tag inside the `<tbody>` with `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;`